# How can write query to select all information where RawMaterialID=1

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

i am designing a project in asp.net mvc3. 
this is my table

[image]

i want to print all information where RawMaterialID=1

please suggest me how should i write query to do this. I am using Entity Framework to access database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lambda expression or can use sql syntax.

```
      var results = (from x in dbContext.MaterialTable
                     where x.RawMaterialID == 1 
                     select x);

      Or 

      var results = dbContext.MaterialTable.Where(r => r.RawMaterialID == 1);
```

Comment: Sir,i appreciate your answer var results = dbContext.MaterialTable.Where(r => r.RawMaterialID == 1); please tell me how can use this results in my view(print.cshtml) to print all results.?

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like

```
var results = dbContext.MyTable.Where(r => r.RawMaterialID == 1);
```

Comment: You are very right sir. I have a problem when i am using this results var in my getFromQuery.cshtml                                        i am using @foreach(var item in results) in my cshtml page, so there is an error that "the name 'results'  does not exist in current context", please tell me what should i do for it ?